# Netbeans + Java 9 Modules + Log4j 2.11 = Module not found

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, log4j, java-9

I use Apache Netbeans 9 Beta 9 (22 February 2018). I have a Java 9 Module application. And I want to integrate `Log4j 2` into my application. Here is my `modile-info.java`.

```
module ru.itlect.remka.agent {

    exports ru.itlect.remka.agent;

    requires ru.itlect.remka.commons;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j.core;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j;

    requires static spring.context;
    requires java.logging;
    requires java.xml;
    requires java.sql;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires java.naming;
    requires java.rmi;

    requires static javafx.graphics;
    requires static javafx.controls;
}
```

**Netbeans says that `org.apache.logging.log4j` module is not found.** Though `org.apache.logging.log4j.core` is OK. When I build the project, it is built successfully. So the problem is in Netbeans itself. `java --list-modules` says that the `org.apache.logging.log4j` is in `log4j-api-2.11.0.jar`.
If I type `requeres log` Netbeans suggests `log4j.api` which the automatic module name for `log4j-api-2.11.0.jar`. Thought Netbeans says that `log4j.api` is ot found either.

I can live with the constant error message in module-info.java, but Netbeans cannot see any class in `log4j-api-2.11.0.jar` so I have errors in any class which uses loggers. **How to make Netbeans see the module?**

This is a part from my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>

    <!-- Ремка -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.itlect.remka</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Spring-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Аннотации -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.5</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: The module name _org.apache.logging.log4j_ is correct. Log4J-API is a [multi-release JAR](https://blog.codefx.org/tools/multi-release-jars-multiple-java-versions/) and defines its name in `versions/9/module.info.class` - my guess is that NetBeans isn't handling that well.

Comment: Same here. I really like to know why the modules would not be seen when they are imported by maven and required in the module-info.java (and I really would love to shoot jigsaw to a VERY FAR AWAY place in space).

Comment: Log4j 2.9 has no support for java 9 modules. So it is treated as an automatic module by both NetBeans and Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too was having trouble updating some applications to use Log4j2 V2.11.1 as a module.  I created a simple test case and raised it on the Netbeans users mailing list.

As of earlier today, a bug in the latest release of Netbeans 9 was found and fixed.  [Pull request 941](https://github.com/apache/incubator-netbeans/pull/941), which Geertjan approved this morning, explains.  The mailing list ([users@netbeans.incubator.apache.org](http://users@netbeans.incubator.apache.org)) contains suggestions for working around the problem ahead of the fix being merged into a new release.  A new release is entering the [NetCAT (Community Acceptance Testing)](https://netbeans.apache.org/participate/netcat.html) process.  The developers would appreciate community help to finish it faster, which is probably the best way forward.

If you need an immediate solution, one suggested approach from the discussion is to edit the jar file to move the module-info.class file into the root structure.